# How to design the application on angular side and node side

Tags: node.js, angular, architecture

Hi wanted to design the application on angular side and node side.

I have added Readme.md for the problem.

I know may be this is not the correct platform to post here but I am not aware of any such platforms were we can discuss these stuffs.

I want to design this application.

https://github.com/jainAdijain/vendorManagementSystem

Comment: This is a pretty big discussion. If you want to talk more to me and some other devs, join our discord group and we can get into the details https://discord.gg/Auh7zDkd

Answer (score 0):

There is an amazing tool for this which provides extensive support for keeping for Application Structure design you can check it over here: https://nx.dev/